# Breeze Error message "; " with status OK in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, cors, odata, breeze

I am using CORS support in WebAPI and get a strange result set from the EntityManager even thought I get status code 200 and data back from the server. The response gets

The error message is (truncated):

```
{message: "; ", statusText: "OK", status: 200, url:"http://localhost:61808/odata/Servers?$filter=Id%20gt%2080&$top=20&$expand=Owner%2CApplications"}
```

My datacontext:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('App').factory('datacontext', datacontext);

  datacontext.$inject = ['EntityManagerFactory'];

  function datacontext(EntityManagerFactory) {
    var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
    var Manager = EntityManagerFactory.newManager();

return {
  getServers: getServers
};

function getServers() {
  return EntityQuery
    .from('Servers')
    .expand('owner, applications')
    .where('id', 'gt', 80)
    .take(20)
    .toType('server')
    .using(Manager)
    .noTracking()
    .execute()
    .then(success)
    .catch(error);
}

function success(response) {
  return response.results;
}

function error(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

My WebAPI web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, MERGE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This code runs fine in Internet Explorer. However, the error is thrown in Chrome even though a payload is delivered! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the current version of datajs 1.1.2 that is filed under issues on codeplex at https://datajs.codeplex.com/workitem/756.

In datajs.js replace readResponseHeaders with:

```
var readResponseHeaders = function (xhr, headers) {
  /// <summary>Reads response headers into array.</summary>
  /// <param name="xhr" type="XMLHttpRequest">HTTP request with response available.</param>
  /// <param name="headers" type="Array">Target array to fill with name/value pairs.</param>

  var responseHeaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().split(/\r?\n/);
  var i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = responseHeaders.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (responseHeaders[i]) {
      var header = responseHeaders[i].split(": ");
      headers[header[0]] = header[1];
    }
  }

  // Fix to handle Firefox CORS bug
  var requiredHeaders = [
    'Content-Type', 'DataServiceVersion'

    /*, 'Content-Length'
     , 'Cache-Control'
     , 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'
     , 'X-Content-Type-Options'
     , 'Date'*/
  ];

  for (i = 0; i < requiredHeaders.length; i++) {
    if (headers[requiredHeaders[i]] === undefined &&
      xhr.getResponseHeader(requiredHeaders[i])) {
      headers[requiredHeaders[i]] = xhr.getResponseHeader(requiredHeaders[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

and in web.config in WebAPI add:

```
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="DataServiceVersion" />
```